# Parsing nested tags with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm using a database API called Socrata to parse information for recycling services. An example of the XML output from this service can be found here:

http://www.datakc.org/api/views/zqwi-c5q3/rows.xml?search=%22computer%22

As you can probably tell, this seems just like *bad XML*. The problem I'm having is that the tag containing the list of rows is called `row` (with no attributes) and each row is also called `row` (with attributes). This seems like it will confuse the hell out of XStream, and I cannot find a way at all to handle this data with XStream.

Any of you XStream/XML gurus out there know what I can do?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I'm afraid that the choice of parser has nothing to do with this. It is involved with how XStream handles the data it reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution wasn't very intuitive but I managed to figure it out. First I had to declare a class that represented the response tag. This class also contains a container of a list of recycle services. Here's how the class looks:

```
@XStreamAlias("response")
public class QueryResponse {

    @XStreamAlias("row")
    private RecycleServices services;

    public RecycleServices getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(RecycleServices services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

}
```

The RecycleServices class is the real trick here, which wraps an implicit List of RecycleService classes.

```
@XStreamAlias("row")
public class RecycleServices {

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "row")
    private List<RecycleService> services = new ArrayList<RecycleService>();

    public List<RecycleService> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(List<RecycleService> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

}
```

The RecycleService class was then just a straight representation of each recycle service row, and is not really relevant to the answer of this question. I had some frustration figuring this out and I hope that this helps someone out there.

Comment: I couldn't for 7 hours after I posted it, so I waited until the next day (today) to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a solution, but the row/element naming would be surmountable by using XSLT to rewrite the DOM to something XStream would be better able to consume.

Comment: This seems a little clunky and complex, especially if the API changes even slightly. I have reason to suspect that XStream can figure this out with some configuration trickery.

Comment: Sure, just an idea, more of a workaround I suppose! Well done on figuring it out.